# Unit (invertible) vs the-unit (neutral) ring element

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $R$ be an Euclidean ring and $a, b \in R$. If $b\neq 0$ and $b$ is not unit in R, show that $d(a)<d(ab)$.

Here is outline of the proof on my book.

Let $A = (a) = \{ x a|x \in R\}$. Then $d(a) \le d(xa)$. If for some $b$, $d(ab) = d(a)$, then the value of $d(ab)$ is minimal in $A$ and $a = abr$ for some $r\in R$. Since $R$ is an integral domain $br = 1$ which shows that $b$ is unit in $R$ contradticting $d(a) = d(ab)$. Hence the proof.

Why does $br =1$ imply $b$ is unit?

Comment: What is your definition of a "unit"? Normally it denotes an invertible element, i.e. a divisor of $1.\ \ $

Comment: Hmmm ... isn't it $c\in R$ such that $bc=b \forall \; b\in R$?

Comment: That's a different meaning of unit (multiplicative identity or neutral element). Usually the two  can be disambiguated by the context, e.g. $ $  $\color{#c00}{the}$ unit, vs. $\color{#c00}{a}$ unit element.

Comment: "a unit" is in my book. You are right ... I find it weird why a unit is defined that way.

Comment: "The" conveys that it is *unique,* so must denote the multiplicative identity, not an arbitrary invertible element.

Comment: so "a unit" is neutral element? divisor of $1$ in R? as my case above??

Comment: In this case, yes. Generally you have to examine the context to infer which is intended. "A unit" can occur either way, e.g. "ring with a unit", or "$(2,m)=1\,$ so $2$ is a unit in $\,\Bbb Z/m.$"

Comment: Well, if you like you can add one line as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I summarized the above in an answer. I think everyone is a bit puzzled the first time they encounter this overloaded terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "unit" is overloaded in ring theory. It can refer either to the multiplicative identity (or neutral element) usually denoted by $1,\,$ or it can refer more generally to any invertible element. If an identity element exists it is unique, so it is often referred to as *the* unit, which helps to distinguish between the two usages. Generally one easily infers from the context which meaning is intended. See also  this [Wikipedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29)